# SQL Query to return different values of a column having same id in another column in same row

Tags: oracle

My table 'Details' looks like this,

```
ID    Name    City
1     Arun    Chennai
2     Arun    Mumbai
3     Raj     Bangalore
4     Raj     Chennai
```

I want to select the same Name containing different values in 'City' column in a single row.

I have written the below query

```
select a.id, b.id, a.Name, a.city, b.city 
from Details a join Details b on a.Name = b.Name
where a.City <> b.City
```

For which the output is

```
id id Name City      City
1  2  Arun Chennai   Mumbai
2  1  Arun Mumbai    Chennai
3  4  Raj  Bangalore Chennai
4  3  Raj  Chennai   Bangalore
```

But I need the output in one row with both id's and City's

```
id id Name City      City
1  2  Arun Chennai   Mumbai
3  4  Raj  Bangalore Chennai
```

Kindly advise

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? Tag only one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select a.id, b.id, a.Name, a.city, b.city 
from Details a 
inner join Details b on a.Name = b.Name and a.id < b.id
```

**Note:** This will work as long as you *always* have two records per `Name`. If you have either one, or two records, then you can use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

**Edit:** If you can have one, two, or three records per `Name`, then your query can be formulated as follows:

```
select a.id, b.id, a.Name, a.city, b.city 
from Details a 
left join Details b on a.Name = b.Name and a.id < b.id
left join Details c on a.Name = c.Name and b.id < c.id
```

**Note:** If the number of records varies dynamically then you have to use some sort of grouping with string concatenation, an equivalent of `GROUP_CONCAT` used in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you @Giorgos

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why you need  IDs & Cities of multiple columns in a same set.

But this may help you (Assumed RDBMS : SQL Server)

```
SELECT NAME, STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + City
            FROM #DETAILS D2
            WHERE D1.NAME = D2.NAME
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') as Cities
FROM #DETAILS D1
GROUP BY NAME
```

This will give you the result like

```
+------+-------------------+
| Name |      Cities       |
+------+-------------------+
| Arun | Chennai,Mumbai    |
| Raj  | Bangalore,Chennai |
+------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your table name. Here I have used inner join.

```
SELECT T1.ID,T2.ID,T1.Name,T1.City,T2.City
FROM your_table T1
INNER JOIN your_table T2
ON T1.ID < t2.ID
WHERE T1.Name = T2.Name
```